# How to print British Pound Sign £ on printer in android code

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEZ0a.jpg)I want to print bill (payment-bill) but it does not display pound sign in receipt?Also i want to print chines character How to solve this problem,Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you could show us the "printing" code?

Comment: Do you have some code? with which we can help you

Comment: use `\u00a3` for displaying pound sign

Comment: just Display in textview but not print inside printer paper

Comment: Find out what character set and character encoding the printer uses and use matching values within the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String pound = "\u00a3";
```

and for more sgins:
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

First you have to initialize printer commands with this code.

```
final byte[] Init = {27, 29, 116, 32};//for star micronics
 final byte[] InitTM = {27,  116, 16};//for other printers.
```

Then you have to use windows 1252 encoding.

```
     String commands = "£ 120";
     byte[] b = new byte[0];
            try {
                b = commands.getBytes("windows-1252");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
public class ExampleEuroPound {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String euro = "\u20ac";
    String pound = "\u00a3";

    System.out.println("pound = " + pound);
    System.out.println("euro = " + euro);
  }
}
```

this may helps you.

More Unicode Characters :  [here](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_common_symbols.html)

**EDIT 1:**

```
byte[] b = pound.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] b = pound.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Java 7+ only
```

then add

```
list.add(pound);
```

**EDIT2:**

This should work.

```
String euro = "\u20ac";
String pound = "\u00a3";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(pound);
list.add(euro);

for(int i = 0 ;i < list.size(); i++){
System.out.println(list.get(i));

}
```

Comment: String pound = "\u00a3";
list.add(pound.getBytes());printer_Obj.write(bytes.get(i));

Comment: make your list as String then try simply list.add(pound);

Comment: list is byte array

Comment: this code not workbyte[] b = pound.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] b = pound.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Java 7+ only
then add

list.add(pound);

Comment: list.add("Table  : T01,   Order#: 10132\n".getBytes());
  list.add("Cust.Cat.: InHouse Clients   \n".getBytes());              
  String pound = "\u00a3";
  byte[] b = pound.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
 
  try {
   list.add(pound.getBytes((Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
   list.add((date + "\n").getBytes("gb2312"));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  
  }
  
  list.add(b);
 
  list.add("------------------------------------------------\n".getBytes());

Comment: list.add("2 x  Duck Pancake        1.2 \n".getBytes());
  list.add("1 x  Chow Mein           2.9 \n".getBytes());
  list.add("1 x  Fried Rice          3.0 \n".getBytes());
  list.add("1 x  Banana Fritter      1.8 \n".getBytes());

Comment: you are adding string. but why do you make list as byte?

Comment: i write data in byte in printer object