# Printing from my hybrid Android App to TM T70II

Tags: javascript, android, printing, epson, pound

Here is my problem. I am trying to print from my app to EPSON Thermal Printer Tm T70II via Bluetooth. I can connect and print but I am not able to print the symbol £ for my receipts.
It prints strange characters and I am struggling to find a solution. Can someone help me with it?
thanks in advance
Raj

```
var uint8array = new TextEncoder('utf-8', { NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true }).encode(print_dtl); //print_dtl is my content

bt.write(uint8array.buffer, deviceId); //Bluetooth print out to the device
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print British Pound Sign £ on printer in android code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678239/how-to-print-british-pound-sign-%c2%a3-on-printer-in-android-code)

Answer (score 0):

I foung the solution.
Used ESC R \3 command and changed to UK char set and then used the hexa decimal sign \u0023 for Pound